# Determine the number of elements that precede a number in two integers: R

Tags: r, double, comparison

I have two long doubles in R called m and n which consist of a variety of numbers:

```
m <- c(3,5,8,12,15,19,21,23,26,33,37,42,45,47,51,54,58,60)
n <- c(13,14,52,53,56,57)
```

I am trying to count the number of entries in m that precede each entry in n, plus 1.

For example, the first entry in n is 13. In m, there are 4 numbers 3,5,8,12, that precede 13, so I would like the program to return 5. For 14, the result that should be returned is also 5. For 52, there are 15 numbers in m preceding 52, so I would like the program to return 16.

Thank you!

Comment: And what have you tried? Can you at least give R code that creates the vectors, rather than us having to edit your text to something we can feed to R? (Hint: use `m = c(......)`)

Comment: By "preceding" do you mean "are less than"? How many numbers in `m` are less than `i` for all `i` in `n`? Plus one.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(n, m) + 1
#[1]  5  5 16 16 17 17
```

Comment: nice!10moretogo

Answer (score 2):

```
m<-c(3,5,8,12,15,19,21,23,26,33,37,42,45,47,51,54,58,60)
n<-c(13,14,52,53,56,57)

sapply(n,function(x){sum(m<x)+1})
```

result:

```
[1]  5  5 16 16 17 17
```

Comment: Plus one. Don't forget the plus one.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: just realised it!

Answer (score 0):

```
 cut(n,m,2:length(m))
[1] 5  5  16 16 17 17
Levels: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

as.numeric(cut(n,m,2:length(m)))+1
[1]  5  5 16 16 17 17

as.numeric(as.character(cut(n,m,2:length(m))))
[1]  5  5 16 16 17 17
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Code only answers are likely to get deleted very soon

Comment: well, in that case, I believe the OP is able to use `?functionName` to get hold of it. I think this solution just shows how many ways exist to solve the same problem.